# IOT Hub - QueryDevice functions missing from RegistryManager?

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

According to Microsoft's api documentation (and their samples for IOT Hub) for the [RegistryManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager.aspx) (Microsoft.Azure.Devices namespace) there should be several "QueryDevices" methods exposed.  Yet when I create a new console app, downloading the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Devices from Nuget, it is no where to be seen in the RegistryManager class definition or intellisense.  I do see many of the other methods like GetDevices, AddDevices, etc.

I am trying to query on my devices so I can send messages to groups of devices.

I have tried multiple versions including: 1.0.14 (latest at the time of writing this), 1.0.11, 1.0.09, and 1.0.2.

Any idea if the Query methods for IOT hub devices were moved to another namespace/class?  Or perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, those Query methods are only available in the pre-release version [1.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.1.0-preview-003). If you want to try them out, tick the "Include prerelease" checkbox in NuGet and get the version `1.1.0-preview-003`.

This can also be verified by checking out the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks). In the master branch, there's no mention of QueryDevices methods. However, in the *dmpreview* branch [they exist](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/dmpreview/csharp/service/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/RegistryManager.cs). Those methods were [added in the end of May](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/commit/40728ff84cfb54f8cc8b4b84006c716fac73ed7d) and haven't made their way to the stable release yet.

Comment: +1 You are exactly right, the pre-release includes these.  Wow, confusing to me they would include pre-release specifics in their api.  Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of frustration.

Comment: @Nate No problem, I was also very confused when I saw that there's no mention of prerelease in MSDN.